# How do you setup an API proxy in the CRA dev server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, create-react-app, http-proxy

I am having issues developing a React app. When in development, my the app runs on `localhost:3000` and my backend server (which hosts the `/api` endpoint) runs on `localhost:80`. The frontend makes calls to `localhost:80/api` but they fail because of the same origin policy (or missing CORS). I tried solving the issue by setting up a proxy in my `package.json` with the following line:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:80"
```

The [Create-React-App docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) say that using a proxy "tells the development server to proxy any unknown requests to your API server..." Now for whatever reason, rather than proxying requests for `/api` to localhost:80, React is signaling a *redirect* (HTTP 301) to localhost:80. This is causing the CORS errors to still occur.

You can see from this screenshot of the network traffic that the front end is making a request for my `/api` endpoint and the backend is signaling to redirect:
[image: network traffic]

The React docs specifically say that using a proxy "avoids CORS issues and error messages" in development, so I expect that I have the correct solution but I am setting it up the wrong way.

Is there a way I can prevent these CORS problems without using a Chrome extension?

Comment: This has nothing to do with using React.js (or not). What development server are you using and how is it configured?

Comment: I don't know what the default server is for CRA, but that would be what is hosting the React app. My api endpoint is hosted on an out of the box Apache HTTP server with a few modules enabled for PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Could it be that it's your Apache server sending the 301 redirects? Do you see the requests in its logs?

Comment: @Bergi I looked at the logs and the Apache server is responding with 200 status codes, but no redirects. However, if I run the React app *without* the Apache server running, [I still get 301 redirects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpxDo.png), which leads me to believe that the CRA dev server is signaling the redirects.

Comment: @CardinalSystem Did you try following the docs on how to configure the proxy yourself? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually Specifically setting `changeOrigin: true` might help.

Comment: @Andria I just tried the http-proxy-middleware, as you suggested. It also results in a redirect.

Comment: @CardinalSystem Perhaps the `autoRewrite` option and `followRedirects` options will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Configuring the Proxy Manually

Following [create-react-app's documentation on configuring the proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually), you need to create the `src/setupProxy.js` file and export a function that adds a proxy middleware to the Express app. They recommend using `http-proxy-middleware`.

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
      followRedirects: true // This will likely fix the redirect issue
    })
  );
};
```

- It is recommended that you put all of your proxy logic into this file and remove the `"proxy"` field from your `package.json`.
- You don't need to import this file anywhere.
- This file only supports Node.js syntax/features.

Comment: `followRedirects` was the magical solution! +75